# How to create Oozie workflow dependencies in hue --workflow--Editor

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

CDH 5.5.2 (hue --workflow--Editor)

==================================

we are sqooping data from different system ERP system, so we are created different independent oozie workflow using the editor(hue --workflow--Editor)
(ex:- ERP1_workflow1, ERP2_workflow2,ERP3_workflow3, ERP4_workflow...ERP7)
each workflow has 4o to 50 sqoop command.hence we created different workflow to run parallel.this will run daily @ particular time.Now we have one more workflow  "final_workflow" which has few hive scripts.this need to run If and only if all the (ex:- ERP1_workflow1, ERP2_workflow2,ERP3_workflow3, ERP4_workflow...ERP7) this is completed successfully.

Please can you suggest/step to be followed,to achieve this dependence in oozie.

Comment: Look into "sub-workflows" and "fork/join". In the end you will have a master Workflow that runs all your existing WF in parallel, then after all have completed, runs the final touch.

Comment: one more use case :-  we created 3 different independent oozie workflow using the editor(hue --workflow--Editor) which run in  different time ex:- 1 ) "ERP1_workflow1" run on saturday 9pm EST                       2) "ERP2_workflow2" run on sunday  9am EST.                                          3) "final_workflow" run on sunday 9PM EST,this should run after successfully  completion of 1& 2 workflow. only.                                               Please can you suggest/step to be followed,to achieve this dependence in oozie.

Comment: That might be possible with an Enterprise scheduler, not with Oozie. Workflows are completeley independent. **Possible workaround:** build one Workflow with the 3 sub-workflows in sequence *but* insert a shell between each, with arg = "wait-until-that-time" >> if shell starts after the deadline, exit immediately, otherwise `sleep` for delta time and exit. But then step 2 may be delayed because of step 1. **Variant:** fork with Step 1 on one hand, "wait-until" then Step 2 on the other, join to "wait-until", then Step 3.

Comment: **Better workaround:** develop a small Java utility that calls Oozie REST API to check whether last exec of Workflow "Step 2" started in last 48h and ended OK, raise an exception if not the case. And start Workflow "Step 3" with that Java action *(or, if you don't like Java, develop a shell script running `oozie` CLI and some `grep`/`sed`)*

Comment: Thanks  Samson Scharfrichter for your suggestion will work on it