# Oozie workflow dependency on other oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have 2 oozie work flows ..say workflow 1 and workflow2. While workflow2 execution, workflow1shld not get triggered. And hence workflow 2 shld also check if workflow1 is executing, if so, it shld wait until its completion and then get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Oozie workflows are independent. You could implement the workaround suggested  here [How to create Oozie workflow dependencies in hue --workflow--Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728616/how-to-create-oozie-workflow-dependencies-in-hue-workflow-editor) : a preliminary java action that calls Oozie REST APIs to check whether wf1 or wf2 is running.